# Как закрепить псевдоэлементы ::before и ::after , чтобы они не слетали при сужении окна браузера?

Tags: html, css

Как закрепить псевдоэлементы ::before и ::after , чтобы они не слетали при сужении окна браузера?

```css
body {
  background-color: darkred;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
}

.container {
  max-width: 980px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.video-gallery {
  max-width: 980px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

iframe {
  float: right;
  margin: 20px 15px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.clear {
  clear: right;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: black 0 0 10px;
}

.container::before {
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/4s4MtTC/cloud.png") no-repeat;
  right: 150px;
  bottom: 130px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(10deg)
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/M59CxXV/oscar.png") no-repeat;
  left: -140px;
  bottom: -160px;
  z-index: 6;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(700deg)
}

.talk {
  width: 90px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  bottom: 220px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 4;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Yk0fX0P/chelovek.png" alt="">
  <div class="talk">And Mihaloscar goes to...</div>
  <h1>Лучшие обзоры BAD COMEDIAN</h1>
</div>https://ibb.co/T8WP1WY
<div class="video-gallery">
  <iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1nX0kF2UwDc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pconHWXO3Ss" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yeqYNOFQDVU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2_bWhf5SdtI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One&display=swap");
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Fredoka One", cursive;
  background-color: darkred;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

section {
  padding: 80px 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 980px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

.video-gallery {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  --galeryWidth: 30px;
  padding: var(--galeryWidth);
}

.video-gallery>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: var(--galeryWidth);
}

.section-wrapper>*:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.video-gallery iframe {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: black 0 0 10px;
}

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-container>.static-img>img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.talk {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/4s4MtTC/cloud.png") no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 25%;
  z-index: 4;
  transform: rotate(30deg) scale(2);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.talk span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(57%, 30%)
}

.oskar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(0.8);
}

@media (max-width: 815px) {
  .oskar {
    left: -30%
  }
  .talk {
    transform: rotate(30deg) scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-wrapper">
      <div class="img-container">
        <div class="static-img">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Yk0fX0P/chelovek.png">
        </div>
        <div class="talk">
          <span>And Mihaloscar goes to...</span>
        </div>
        <div class="oskar">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/M59CxXV/oscar.png">
        </div>
      </div>


      <h1>Лучшие обзоры BAD COMEDIAN</h1>
      <p>https://ibb.co/T8WP1WY</p>
      <div class="video-gallery">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1nX0kF2UwDc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pconHWXO3Ss" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yeqYNOFQDVU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2_bWhf5SdtI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .container -->
</section>
```